# CORS and modifying the response header

Tags: javascript, security, cors, cross-domain

I understand that for site A to make a request to site B, site B must specify in it's header response that site A is allowed access by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com`
Also  [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-cors) site states that

> Enabling cross-origin requests is easy, so please, please, please
>   enable CORS if your data is public!

which makes sense to me.

My question is that even if my site B has NOT specified the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for site A, I can still gain access to the data through client side JS on site A by using a Chrome plugin or disable web security. This doesn't make sense.  **How can the client modify the servers response headers and site A still get access to the data through JS?**

Btw site A in this case is `localhost:9000` if that matters.

Comment: The browsers is responsible for same-origin policy. If you disable web security, you simply tell your browser to ignore it. There's no modifying response headers.

Comment: I don't really get your question. If you disable web security or use a Chrome extension, it's the same as if you were making request with `curl` -- there's no same-origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

> How can the client modify the servers response headers and site A still get access to the data through JS

Well, it can't. The thing is that server only replies with CORS header, and how to interpret it is a browser responsibility. You still can, for example, by `curl` retrieve data from any website in the Internet. CORS headers is just a convention.